# How to call a method after WCF Service class is constructed?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to call the method "**StartListen()**" after the WCFService() constructor is called, I can call this method "StartListen()" after the first client call but irrespective of the client call, I want to do this after the service class is constructed, is it possible to do? or is there any other mechanism available for this need?

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] 
public class WCFService : IWCFService
{
    public WCFService()
    {
        // do initializing here
    }

     // implementation of the operation contract 
     public void NotifyToService()
     {
        // method will be called by the client
     }   

    //this internal method has to be called after the class is constructed
    public void StartListen()
     {
        // some listening action
     }     

}
```

Comment: Why not do your thing at the end of the constructor logic then?

Comment: Method is an endless loop listener. Client calling method in the  Client Proxy dll will be called by a windows service using the .Net Reflection, I have to listen those client calls.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are are using `InstanceContextMode.Single` the "simplest" way to do it is a private flag you check to see if the loop has been started and start it if it has not.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] 
public class WCFService : IWCFService
{
    public WCFService()
    {
        // do initializing here
    }

     // implementation of the operation contract 
     public void NotifyToService()
     {
        CheckForStartListen();
        // method will be called by the client
     }   

    //this internal method has to be called after the class is constructed
    public void StartListen()
    {
        // some listening action

    } 

     private readonly Object _initizeLockObject = new Object();
     private bool _initialized = false;


    private void CheckForStartListen()
    {
        if(_initialized)
            return;

        lock(_initizeLockObject)
        {
            if(_initialized) //Double checked locking to see if it was initialized while we wait
                return;

            StartListen();
            _initialized = true;
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: This is not working, I am getting time out error when calling from the client.

Comment: I wrote this assuming `Start`Listen would just start whatever needed starting then return quickly. If StartListen is actually a long running method (like a message loop) then you need to refactor your code so whatever action it is doing runs on a separate thread. If you edit your original question and include some of the code of StartListen I can give some recommendations on how you would need to change it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, let me explain my problem, may be I will post a separate question. When the client calls the method, it is an annunciation for the service, in the background I need to start to perform some actions, lets say 10 clients are calling consequently then one background action is enough. this processing time should not affect the client calling, that's why I want to write listening method,now the new approach is,when client calls the method xml will be created in a folder and I am planning to use system folder watcher to perform some actions.

Comment: It is a little hard to follow what you are trying to do via the limitations of the comment system. I recommend you open a new question with more details.

Comment: Yes, here you go, this is my problem.now I service will create a xml file and file system watcherhas to perform that task when the file created, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789228/annunciating-the-windows-service-to-execute-some-time-consuming-task-using-files